Another question about successors in the preorder of sets in ZF
We write $X\leq Y$ if there is an injection from $X$ into $Y$ and $X < Y$ if $X\leq Y$ and there is no injection from $Y$ into $X$. We say $Y$ is a successor of $X$ if $X<Y$ and there is no $Z$ such that $X<Z<Y$.
Is it consistent with ZF for there to be sets $X, X^+, Y$ with $X^+$ being a successor of $X$ such that there is a $Z$ such that $X+Y<Z<X^++Y$?

What does $+$ mean here?

@Arthur Disjoint union

Obviously not possible in $ZFC$.

Minor observation: assuming WLOG that $X\subset X^+$, note that we must have $X^+\setminus X$ be infinite.

What about infinite Dedekind-finite sets?
